# php ini creating arrays with parse_ini_file

Tags: php, ini

Is it possible to create an array with a settings file?

In the `index.php` file there it reads `.ini` file:

```
// Parse config file
$settings = parse_ini_file("settings");
```

E.g. Settings file looks like this:

```
[States]
east = "Michigan, New York, Minnesota"
```

Looking to create an array like so:

```
array('Michigan', 'New York', 'Minnesota')
```

Comment: That's exactly what `parse_ini_file()` returns: an associative array. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: Are you wanting to create an array that looks like: `("Michigan", "Alaska", "Minnesota")` ?

Comment: @JonathanM yes i'm trying to create an array that looks like (Michigan, Alaska, Minnesota)

Comment: @chrisjlee, my answer will do that for you -- the explode function takes a delimeted string and converts it to an array

Comment: Chris: any chance you could change the accepted answer, for the benefit of others (like me) looking up this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It returns an associative array. Then, to parse the east states into an array, you could do:
`$eastStates = explode(', ', $ini['States']['east']);` if your data is indeed in the format you described. Note that you can create true arrays in ini format, see [the documentation](http://mx.php.net/parse_ini_file).

Comment: For the OP: Alaskans (as well as folks in the other listed states) will be glad to know they're on the east coast. :) Maybe we're selling Alaska to Russia?

Answer (score 55):

The right way to create an array in your ini file is with brackets:

```
[States]
east[] = Michigan
east[] = New York
east[] = Minnesota
```

You can see an example in the [documentation for `parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php):